# Normal subgroup related

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

let $G$ be a finite group and $N$ be the normal subgroup of $G$ of index $p$, a prime number. Then what is number of all subgroups of $G$ containing $N$?

I don't have idea

Comment: Hint: The subgroups of $G$ containing $N$ are in $1-1$ correspondence with the subgroups of $G/N$, and given the index of $N$ this quotient group should be easy to understand.

Comment: This one-to-one correspondence is called (any guesses?) the [correspondence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_%28group_theory%29).

Comment: Answer should be $p$?